# BlackJack Classes

Tags: python-3.x, class, blackjack

I am not receiving an error but can't get my classes to function properly.
I am trying to get Card class to print "two of hearts" but I get nothing when I run it. Also testing my deck class I get `<__main__.Deck object at 0x0000029A1F045F70>` which I cant recall how to correct.

```
import random


suits = ['spades', 'hearts', 'clubs', 'diamonds']
ranks = ['two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace']
values = {'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5, 'six': 6, 'seven': 7, 'eight': 8, 'nine': 9, 'ten': 10, 'jack': 10, 'queen': 10, 'king': 10, 'ace': 11}

playing = True

class Card:
    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

    def show(self):
        print("{} of {}".format(self.value, self.suit))

            

card_picked = Card('two', 'hearts')

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
       self.cards = []
       self.build()

    def build(self):
        for i in values:
            for s in suits:
                self.cards.append(Card(i, s))

    def show(self):
        for c in self.cards:
            c.show()

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self):
        single_card = self.cards.pop()
        return single_card

deck = Deck()
print(deck)
```

Thank you in advance for any help provided!

Comment: You need to implement the [`__str__`](https://realpython.com/lessons/how-and-when-use-str/) method and show whatever you want to show each time you want to print an instance of that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print() accesses the __str__ method of a class if that method exists.

You can define it for your Card class:

```
class Card:
    
    [...]
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} of {}".format(self.value, self.suit)
```

for the entire deck, you can get the __str__ methods of every card in that deck:

```
class Deck:

    [...]

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join([c.__str__() for c in self.cards])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine.

```
deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()
card = deck.deal()
card.show()
```

I get output:

```
six of hearts
```